# Merge multiple columns in bulkloader

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I'm using app engine's `bulkloader` to import a CSV file into my datastore. I've got a number of columns that I want to merge into one, for example they're all URLs, but not all of them are supplied and there is a superseding order, eg:

```
url_main
url_temp
url_test
```

I want to say: "Ok, if `url_main` exists, use that, otherwise user `url_test` and then use `url_temp`"

Is it, therefore, possible to create a custom import transform that references columns and merges them into one based on conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after reading https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader I learnt about `import_transform` and that this can use custom functions.

With that in mind, this pointed me the right way:

> ... a two-argument function with the keyword argument bulkload_state,
>   which on return contains useful information about the entity:
>   bulkload_state.current_entity, which is the current entity being
>   processed; bulkload_state.current_dictionary, the current export
>   dictionary ...

So, I created a function that handled two variables, one would be the `value` of the current entity and the second would be the `bulkload_state` that allowed me to fetch the current row, like so:

```
def check_url(value, bulkload_state):
    row = bulkload_state.current_dictionary
    fields = [ 'Final URL', 'URL', 'Temporary URL' ]

    for field in fields:
        if field in row:
            return row[ field ]


    return None
```

All this does is grab the current row (`bulkload_state.current_dictionary`) and then checks which URL fields exist, otherwise it just returns `None`.

In my `bulkloader.yaml` I call this function simply by setting:

```
- property: business_url
  external_name: URL
  import_transform: bulkloader_helper.check_url
```

Note: the `external_name` doesn't matter, as long as it exists as I'm not actually using it, I'm making use of multiple columns.

Simples!

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, genius! I wanted to generate an `URL` field **during** bulkload based on my `NAME` field. 
In `bulkloader.yaml`
1. added `- import: bulkloader_helper`
2. used `import_transform: bulkloader_helper.createurl`
Then created new file `bulkloader_helper.py`:
`import string
def createurl(value, bulkload_state):
  url = bulkload_state.current_dictionary['country']
  url = string.replace(url," ","-") #replace spaces with hyphens
  url = string.translate(url, "(),'.") #delete unwanted punctuation
  url = string.lower(url) #make lowercase
  return url`